# Postgresql change type GEOCOORD_T to POINT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table `locations` where coordinates are saved in a column `geocoord` of type :
`geocoord_t` and the output is `"(12.345678,-0.123456)"`

Has it isn't particularly useful, I want to change this column to the type `point`.
With `ALTER TABLE` maybe, but I don't know how to convert strings to point type.

How can I make that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have the `geocoord_t` data type so this is a bit of guesswork, but the general procedure is like this:

```
ALTER TABLE locations ALTER COLUMN geocoord SET DATA TYPE point;
```

If there is no automatic conversion from `geocoord_t` to `point` then you have to append a `USING` clause. Seeing that `geocoord_t` outputs its value in a text format that the `point` data type can ingest, it could be as easy as:

```
... SET DATA TYPE point USING geocoord::text
```

otherwise use a more elaborate expression like:

```
... SET DATA TYPE point USING point(geocoord.longitude, geocoord.latitude)
```

or whatever other options the `geocoord_t` type supports. The second option is probably faster because it avoids conversion from binary to text to binary.

Comment: thanks, I think it's a text type, but executing your second command output : `column “geocoord” cannot be cast to type point`

Comment: But is there a way to convert text to point using regex-like expression or string manipulation function ?

Comment: The `point` type will accept a string in a variety of formats, including the text output of the `geocoord_t`. The first option of casting it to `text` should then work.

Comment: Okay I resolved it : 
There was a view using this table so I removed it temporaly,
I converted the `geocoord_t` to `text` :
`ALTER TABLE locations ALTER COLUMN "geocoord" SET DATA TYPE text USING (geocoord::text)`
And then `text` to `point` :
`ALTER TABLE locations ALTER COLUMN "geocoord" SET DATA TYPE point USING (geocoord::text::point)`
Thank for your Help.